# Evaluating $\lim_{(x,y) \to (\pi,0)} {\cos(x) + 1 + {y^2/2} \over (x - \pi)^2 + y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm struggling to evaluate this limit problem:

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (\pi,0)} {\cos x + 1 + {y^2/2} \over (x - \pi)^2 + y^2}$$

I've tried this with paths $x=\pi$, $y=0$, $y=x-\pi$, ... and so far all of them have resulted in $1 \over 2$. However when I try to evaluate this in WolframAlpha, it says that the limit does not exist.

I haven't found any paths that result in a value other than $1/2$. How can I prove that this limit does not exist?

Comment: Are you sure the limit does not exist? How so?

Comment: @Fabian Not really, but I've checked multiple similar functions with WolframAlpha and it answered correctly for all of them, so I took its word on this one as well.

Comment: This is tricky :-) both 1-variable limits result in $$\frac{1-u}{u^2} \to \frac12 \leftarrow \frac{y^2/2}{y^2}$$

Comment: @adfriedman in your expression, set $y=0$ and let $u=x-\pi$ to get the left side of my comment, and set $x = \pi$ to get the right side...

Comment: @gt6989b: The OP says he has "tried this with paths $x=\pi$, $y=0$..." so there's nothing new there.

Comment: @BasirDoost Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Let $u=x-\pi$, then

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(\pi,0)}\frac{\cos(x)+1+y^2/2}{(x-\pi)^2+y^2}
= 
\lim_{(u,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{-\cos(u)+1+y^2/2}{u^2+y^2}$$

Note that for small $u$, $\cos(u)=1-u^2/2+O(u^4)$, hence
\begin{align}
\lim_{(u,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{-\cos(u)+1+y^2/2}{u^2+y^2}
&=\lim_{(u,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{u^2/2+O(u^4)+y^2/2}{u^2+y^2}\\
&= \lim_{(u,y)\to(0,0)}\left[\frac12 + \frac{O(u^4)}{u^2+y^2}\right]
=\tfrac12
\end{align}

Comment: why are you sure that there is no other $x,y$ path that results in a different outcome?

Comment: @gt6989b, What was the path that he's taken?

Comment: @AlexSilva a linear one

Comment: @gt6989b I am using a linear transformation, not a linear path... I don't define the path, except that it has to get close to $u=0$ or $x=\pi$ eventually.

Comment: That’s not the correct expression for the big-O term.

Comment: @gimusi, The big O notation is correct.

Comment: @gt6989b: There's no particular path being taken here. Indeed if we rewrite it to polar form, $(u,v)=(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ the error term is $O(r^4 \cos^4\theta)/r^2$, which is $O(r^4)/r^2=O(r^2)$ because $\cos^4\theta$ is bounded. The $\theta$ has disappeared, and the error goes to $0$ as $r\to 0$, independently of any particular path -- directly from the definition of convergence.

Comment: @AlexSilva it should be $O(u^4+y^4)$

Comment: @gimusi No, where would the $y^4$ term come from?

Comment: It’s a Taylor’s expansion in 2 variables

Comment: @gimusi No, it's a Taylor expansion in one variable, $u$. Just because it's a multivariable limit does not mean every term is multivariable

Comment: It’s not correct, see the comment by Henning Makholm

Comment: @gimusi That comment was agreeing with me. They used polar substitution, $u=r\cos \theta$, so the error term (for the numerator) given was $O(r^4 \cos^4 \theta) = O(u^4)$

Comment: @adfriedman ok sorry now I get your point, both $O(u^4)$ and $O(|u,y|^4)$ are correct, even if with the second $O(|u,y|^4)/(u^2+y^2)\to 0$ is  a little bit straightforward to obtain.

Answer (score 1):

You should try $x' = x - \pi$ and then $$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (\pi,0)} {\cos x + 1 + {y^2/2} \over (x - \pi)^2 + y^2} = \lim\limits_{(x',y) \to (0,0)} {1-\cos x' + {y^2/2} \over (x')^2 + y^2}$$
$$=  \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} {1-\cos x \over x^2 + y^2} + \frac{1}{2} {{y^2} \over x^2 + y^2}$$
$$=  \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} { 2\sin^2(x/2) \over x^2 + y^2} + \frac{1}{2} { y^2 \over x^2 + y^2}$$
$$=  \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2}{x^2+y^2} \left ({\sin^2(x/2)\over (x/2)^2} \right) + {\frac{1}{2}y^2\over x^2 + y^2}$$

$$=  \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2}{x^2+y^2} \left (1+{\sin^2(x/2)\over (x/2)^2} - 1 \right) + {\frac{1}{2}y^2\over x^2 + y^2}$$

$$=  \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2 + y^2}{x^2+y^2} + \lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} \left ( {\sin^2(x/2)\over (x/2)^2} - 1\right )  $$
$$= \frac{1}{2}  $$

Answer (score 0):

By the change of variable

- $u=x-\pi\to 0$
- $v=y\to 0$

we have that

$$\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (\pi,0)} {\cos(x) + 1 + {y^2/2} \over (x - \pi)^2 + y^2}=\lim\limits_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} {{1-\cos u+v^2/2} \over u^2+v^2}=\lim\limits_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} {{u^2/2+v^2/2+o(u^2+v^2)} \over u^2+v^2}=\lim\limits_{(u,v) \to (0,0)} \frac12 +\frac{o(u^2+v^2)}{u^2+y^2}
=\frac12$$

Comment: commenting.....